# CSS flexbox centering with a fixed width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a wrapper using flex box and fixed width.  When I add a fixed width to the body like 100% and use margin: 0 auto; everything is thrown off center.  I would like the wrapper to have a fixed width of 1000px and centered within the body (this is why I'm setting the body to 100%).

Any help is appreciated.  HTML and CSS below.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Flex box layout</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webtemp.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <article class="main">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>  
  </article>
  <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>
  <aside class="aside aside-2">Aside 2</aside>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.main {
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
}

.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside {
    flex: 1 auto;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main {
    flex: 3 0px;
  }

  .aside-1 {
    order: 1;
  }

  .main {
    order: 2;
  }

  .aside-2 {
    order: 3;
  }

  .footer {
    order: 4;
  }
}
body {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

Comment: best way to show your problem in, code snippet tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply fixed width and use `margin:0px auto;` to align center.

```
.wrapper {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
flex-flow: row wrap;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
width:300px;
margin:0px auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/j8qqcfrb/)

Comment: I should have been more specific that I was trying to center at the body level and then set a width on .wrapper.  I went with this solution as this does works and unblocks me.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

just set the width of `.wrapper` to `1000px;`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width:1000px;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.main {
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
}

.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside {
    flex: 1 auto;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main {
    flex: 3 0px;
  }

  .aside-1 {
    order: 1;
  }

  .main {
    order: 2;
  }

  .aside-2 {
    order: 3;
  }

  .footer {
    order: 4;
  }
}
body {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <article class="main">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>  
  </article>
  <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>
  <aside class="aside aside-2">Aside 2</aside>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

emphasized text